# change npm install path for global packages to a custom directory

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I want to configure my node setup such that it stores global modules (installed using `npm install -g <pkg>` to (and also reads from) a custom directory `D:\node_modules`. default path is `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm` . Any pointers would be much appreciated.

OS is Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found answer in `npm help`. Had to set `prefix` config:

`D:> npm config set prefix "D:\node_modules"`